# Does a CIP IDS require a copy of the parent US application?

Tags: continuation-in-part, ids

I'm filing 2 CIPs on a US parent application that was published less than a year ago, with the specification cross-referencing the parent and a couple of later provisionals. Should the IDSs list any of those cross-referenced applications, and are copies required?

Answer (score 2):

The IDS does not need to list any U.S. applications that are claimed as priority applications. It should list everything listed on the IDSs on all previous applications or cited against them.

You do not need copies of U.S. patent applications.